# Pass parameters from router to controller in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a route that is defined as such

`router.route('/:id/organisers').get(HackathonControllers.getHackathonRoles());`

Now, the `getHackathonRoles` is a controller defined as such for example:

```
function getHackathonRoles(role, req, res, next) {
    console.log(role);
    res.status(200).json({
        message: `Successfully updated Hackathon ${hackathonId}, published status updated to ${hackathonPublishedStatus}`
    })
}
```

What I ideally want to do is pass in a role by defining multiple router endpoints. Something like:

`router.route('/:id/organisers').get(HackathonControllers.getHackathonRoles(role='organiser'));`

And

`router.route('/:id/volunteer').get(HackathonControllers.getHackathonRoles(role='volunteer'));`

So basically I want to reuse the `getHackathonRoles` method and want to avoid rewriting the same method for different roles. I ideally, I should be able `console.log(role)` in the controller.

As of now, this fails and I get the error:

> router.route('/:id/organisers').get(_hackathonController2.default.getHackathonRoles(role
>   = 'organiser'));

How do I work around this and keep it sort of DRY? I *don't want to incorporate parameters* into the endpoint like `/:id/?` and the arguments are like `role=organiser` or `role=volunteer` etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `get` function expects a callback with the signature `(req, res, next)` so you cannot just pass arbitrary parameters and expect it to work. Instead, you have to call a function that returns such a function by itself.

```
function getHackathonRoles(role) {
    console.log(role);
    return function(req, res, next) {
        // do something with the role variable
        // send a response using res.status(...).json(...)
    });
}

router.route('/:id/organisers').get(getHackathonRoles('organiser'));
router.route('/:id/volunteer').get(getHackathonRoles('volunteer'));
```

Comment: Ahh that's super smart. So this is a closure of sorts?

Comment: @bholagabbar Exactly.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly. Thanks! Fantastic solution. Still can't get over how you figured it out

Comment: @bholagabbar Well, in JavaScript [functions are first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and this approach is very common :)

Comment: Yes, it's been quite a ride switching from Java webapps to building full fledged services in NodeJS. Still learning! :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
app.get("/users/:userId/books/:bookId", (req, res) => {
  // Access userId via: req.params.userId
  // Access bookId via: req.params.bookId
  res.send(req.params);
});
```